# Calling `strcat` and being able to store a larger size string into a smaller one?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

How is it possible to store all of `str2` which have size 5 in `str1` which have only size 2?

Am I hacking the system?

The textbook state to make sure that `str1` must have a larger value to store `str2`, but why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char str1[2] = {'B', '\0'};
    char str2[5] = {'c', 'o', 'l', 'l', '\0'};
    std::strcat(str1, str2);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have _undefined behavior_, that simple.

Comment: Yes you are. The two variables are on the stack and you are overriding part of str2. Don't do that, that's what `string` are for.

Comment: what do you mean with undefined behavior?

Comment: Exceeding the bounds of the array is undefined behavior.

Comment: Literally behaviour that is not defined by the C++ Standard. Because forcing checks for buffer overruns onto programs that do not overrun buffers is an unnecessary performance penalty, the C++ standard leave what happens open to the programmer implementing the library. Most of the time they do nothing (maximum performance) and let the program do what you asked. Sometimes they build in checks. Sometimes the behaviour is what you want. Sometimes it isn't. Sometimes it looks like it it, but isn't.

Comment: undefined behavior is when you do something that is not specified by the language. going out of bounds of an array is an example. When you do undefined behavior, anything can happen

Comment: i see but then why did the textbook state to make sure that str1 must be large enough to store str2?

Comment: *The textbook state to make sure that str1 must have a larger value to store s2* -- The reason why the textbook says this is that you will have a broken program if it is not large enough.

Comment: Because if `str1` is not large enough to store `str2` you don't have any way of knowing what will happen. It might work for a while. It might work forever. It might crash your computer. It might make your computer simulate a rain of Care Bears and unicorns.

Comment: so it might work with small strings but might crash with large strings?

Comment: @user10798572 -- It doesn't "work" regardless of the size of the string.  If you overflow the array, anything can happen.  If I took the program you wrote, and ran it on a runtime that checks these things such as buffer overflow, the runtime will halt your program with an `assert` or similar error.

Comment: A good example with stack behaviour (and there's no guarantees the system has a stack) is TYPICALLY the computer will write over the variables around the receiving string in the stack. This may cause the program to crash a month from now when it looks at that overwritten variable and finds an invalid value. Often this has you debugging the wrong problem, checking to see who set a bad value rather than looking at the invalid string writing code. This is essentially the behaviour Acorn is describing in their answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have this in the stack:

```
str1 ---> [X, X]
str2 ---> [Y, Y, Y, Y, Y]
```

Where each `X` and `Y` are single `char` objects (i.e. typically a byte of memory each).

When you call `strcat(str1, str2)`, you are asking to put 5 `Y`s starting at the first `\0` in `str1` (until the first `\0` in `str2`, which in this case is the last one).

So the first `Y` goes into the second part of `str1`, which is fine:

```
str1 ---> [X, Y]
str2 ---> [Y, Y, Y, Y, Y]
```

But then `strcat` will continue writing outside of the array the other 4 `Y`s that are left, i.e. it will "try" the following:

```
str1 ---> [X, Y] Y, Y, Y, Y
str2 ---> [Y, Y, Y, Y, Y]
```

That is a mistake which triggers undefined behavior, which means your program has a bug (what happens exactly depends: it may crash, misbehave or it may work just by luck).

As your textbook says, the solution is to have `str1` be big enough to fit, at least, all of it:

```
str1 ---> [X, Y, Y, Y, Y, Y]
str2 ---> [Y, Y, Y, Y, Y]
```

In other words, `str1` must be an array of at least 6 elements.